# javascript anonymous function scope behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I have a code that kind of follows this pattern:

```
a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
m = {};

for(i=0;i<10;i++){
  m[a.charAt(i)] = function(){
      return i;
  };
}

console.log(m.c());
```

it returns 10.

WHY the heck does it do that? 
And how could I get it to return the corresponding number?

**------- EDIT -------**

Thank for your great responses. The answers that have been provided so far work for the above example, but I forgot to mention that I need to pass a callback function. Taking your advice into consideration I came up with this:

```
a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
m = {};

f = function(i) {
    return function(){
        return i;
    }
}

for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    var eval('n') = "hi";
    console.log(n);
    m[a.charAt(i)] = function(fn){
        fn(f(i));
    };
}

m.c(function(a){console.log(a);});
```

and the outcome agreed with my intuition that it would not work. Does anyone have any ideas for this?

**Thanks for your help**

As a result of your help here I was able to start this project: 
https://github.com/sbussard/python-for-node

Please feel free to continue to contribute as you wish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cage variables in a loop without changing them.

**Non desired behaviour**

```
> myFunctions = new Array() 
[object Array]

for(var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) myFunctions[i] = function() { return i; } 

> myFunctions[0]() 
3

> myFunctions[1]() 
3

> myFunctions[2]() 
3
```

**Fixed**

```
>myFunctions = new Array() 
[object Array]

function mkFunctionWithCagedValue(value) { 
    return function() { 
        return value;
    };
} 

> for(var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) myFunctions[i] = mkFunctionWithCagedValue(i) 
[object Function]

> myFunctions[0]() 
0

> myFunctions[1]() 
1

> myFunctions[2]() 
2
```

Comment: This seems to work, but what I forgot to include was that I also need to pass a callback to the function. Sort of like this: myFunction[0](function(n){alert(n);});

Comment: @Stephen: Well... No Problem. Just use `function mkFunctionWithCagedValue(value) { return function(f) { f();};}` instead of the slightly different line in my example. Or is there more to it?

Comment: Maybe I don't quite understand what you mean, because my tests lead me to that sort of thing doesn't work. Here's what I've got currently: a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
m = {};
function r(fn,v) { return function() { return fn(v);};}
for(i=0;i<10;++i) m[a.charAt(i)] = r(fn,i);
m.c(function(a){console.log(a);}); and I get the error that fn is not defined.

Comment: the same error occurs as well with this statement change: for(i=0;i<10;++i) m[a.charAt(i)] = function(fn){r(fn,i)};

Comment: I can truly say I have learned two incredible things about javascript and programming in general. It works! I think it's just incredible that the code you just provided actually works and it implicitly passes the callback function to r. I'm officially impressed!

Answer (score 3):

The function references the variable `i`. At when the function is executed (at the `console.log()` line), it prints the variable, which has a value of `10` at that time.

To work around this problem you need to create a new variable in each iteration that gets assigned the current value of `i`. To get a new variable scope in each iteration you can use an additional function:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
  function use_copy() {
    var icopy = i; # a new variable to hold the value of i
    return (function(){
      # original function, now using icopy
      return icopy;
    });
  }
  m[a.charAt(i)] = use_copy();
}
```

Comment: creating the function each time inside the loop is unnecessary. Declare the function outside which takes one argument (i) and set `m[a.charAt(i)] = use_copy(i);` instead

Comment: Great! Is there any ways I could also pass a callback function?

Answer (score 0):

** **EDITED** **

Your variable `i` inside your loop equals `10` at the time you call `m.c()` and since it is used in your function, it returns `10` for each "index". Just *save* a copy of this variable. For example :

```
someFunction = function() {
   alert(i);  // will alert 10 because using i from the loop!
};
a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
m = {};

for(i=0;i<10;i++){
  m[a.charAt(i)] = (function(i, callback) {
     // i is a local copy!
     return function() {
        callback();   // invoke callback function
        return i;
     };
  })(i, someFunction);
}

console.log(m.c());  // would return 2
```